# Lógica de paginação com angular e mysql

Tags: mysql, angularjs, paginação

Gostaria de saber como implemento uma lógica de paginação no banco usando mysql e angular no front-end com ui-bootstrap ou dirPagination. Por exemplo, pegando de 10 em 10 no banco usando `LIMIT` e `OFFSET`. Minha dúvida é na implementação da lógica no front-end. Pode ser uma explicação simples e algum exemplo.

Como é uma API, tenho dúvida quanto aos endpoints também. Ficariam parecidos com os exemplos abaixo? Gostaria de um exemplo também.

```
GET /recursos?offset=10&limit=10
GET /recursos/limit/:limit/offset/:offset
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geralmente eu uso esses parâmetros como `query params` assim eles ficam opcionais e eu devolvo sempre com um valor default caso não seja passado nenhum parâmetro, tipo 1º página com 10 itens.

```
GET /recursos?pagina=1&total=10
```

Recebendo esses parâmetros no back, faça:

```
int offset = (pagina < 1 ? 0 : pagina-1) * total;
int limit = offset + total
```

Lembre-se de devolver a quantidade total de itens no banco, fazendo um `COUNT` sem limit e offset para o seu front saber quanto ele ainda pode requisitar do back.

Um bom componente que ja te resolve isso no front é o [ngTable](http://ng-table.com/#/), onde você precisa apenas informar qual página atual, o total de itens que podem ser retornados e a quantidades e itens por página.

Comment: Deu certo, @Giovane, obrigado. Só está trazendo um pouco mais de registro, mas deve ser algum erro na minha lógica, fiz usando o dirPagination porque não consegui usar o ng-table. Como acrescento o total de itens na resposta em json? Estou usando node.js e o retorno está assim: `return res.status(200).json(result);`

Comment: Faça a query com um count depois de fazer ela paginada. Assim você terá o número total de registros, aí no retorno envie um objeto com o total e os resultados paginados. Ex: `return res.status(200).json({ total: countResult, conteudo: 'result' });`

Comment: Saiu 'result' como string pq meu cel auto corrigiu. O 'result' é o seu objeto de result.